# JQuery selectors: use of document, body and quotes inconsistent

Tags: jquery, selector

Basic selectors are of the forms:

```
jQuery( element )
jQuery( selector [, context ] )
```

HTML elements work fine if quoted:

```
$("div").length    // value is 2
$("body").length   // value is 1
$(body).length     // Uncaught ReferenceError: body is not defined
```

Yet document and document.body both work without quotes:

```
$(document).length         // value is 1
$(document.body).length    // value is 1
$("document").length       // value is 0
$("document.body").length  // value is 0
```

Question 1: Are there any other jQuery elements/selectors that work without quotes?

Question 2: Why does document and document.body fail with quotes?

I understand "document" is not an HTML element like `<body>` and may be a special case. Which leads me to my last question.

Question 3: Why does document.body work but the following return a length of 0?

```
$(document.body.div).length         // value is 0
$("document.body.div").length       // value is 0
```

jQuery selector syntax:  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-elementArray

CSS 3 selectors:   http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#type-selectors

Comment: both `document` and `document.body` are defined, where as `body` and `document.body.div` aren't unless you define it. Where is the confusion? jquery isn't doing any magic, it still has to follow all the syntax rules of javascript.

Comment: These are basics of javascript, I would recommend at least to read about JavaScript programing before you start using jQuery or any other JavaScript framework.

Comment: window will work without quotes too, because it is defined. Be aware than in most modern browser, ID of element becomes property of window object so e.g: $(slider) will work if you have any element with ID slider

Comment: Who downvoted this? The OP clearly doesn't understand that `document` is an object with a reference to `body`, so this question is a valid question, clearly articulated. The OP **did** "demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved". Don't downvote simply because you think the answer is trivial!!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`document` isn't an element in the DOM.  It *is* the DOM.  And JavaScript has an object for it in scope ready to be used.  So this selector:

```
$(document)
```

is referencing that object, wrapping it in the jQuery function to create a jQuery object based on the original object.  This same thing happens a lot.  For example, you can do this:

```
var someElement = document.getElementById('someId');
```

Now `someElement` is an object.  (Which coincidentally happens to refer to an HTML element in the DOM, but that's not important.)  And it can be wrapped as a jQuery object:

```
$(someElement)
```

Additionally, `document.body` works because `body` is a property on the `document` object.  This object, and its properties, exist in plain JavaScript as part of the engine overall and aren't part of jQuery.

On the other hand, `$("document")` doesn't work because it's telling jQuery to find an HTML element *called* "document" *inside* the DOM.  Something like:

```
<document>some text</document>
```

Naturally, this doesn't exist.  Nor does this:

```
$("document.body")
```

Because, again, this is using a jQuery selector instead of an existing object.  This selector is looking again for an element called "document" and specifically with a `class` called "body", like this:

```
<document class="body">some text</document>
```

It doesn't exist, so no such element is found by the selector.

Your first examples are just using JavaScript objects, which exist.  Your second examples are using jQuery selectors which are attempting to find elements in the DOM which don't exist.  They're very different.

Answer (score 1):

1. when you use `$(body)` it tries to access a variable called `body` but it is not declared anywhere so it throws a reference error. But `document` is a variable declared in the global scope which refers to the current document object that is why it is working. `document.body` is a property of `document` object so that also works.
2. when you use `'document'` or `'document.body'` it consider it as element selectors and looks for elements like `<document>` in the dom which will not be found
3. `document.body.div` returns undefined so `$(document.body.div)` will not return any result

Answer (score 1):

1. You can pass a DOM object to the jQuery selector, no problem. `document` is the root node for all DOM objects on the page.
2. There is no element on the page named "document", and so quoting it for the selector fails.
3. While `document` has a property `body`, `document.body` does not have a property `div`, hence the first (unquoted) version fails. The second (quoted) version fails for the same reason "document" alone fails.